# ListBoxItem border is sometimes hidden behind the ListBox's scrollbar

Tags: wpf, listbox, listboxitem

Most of the time the ListBox appears like this:

[image]

But every once in a while it looks like this:

[image]

Any idea of what is going wrong?

**--Edit--**

I removed the control templates from the question, because when I removed them from my program the problem still existed. Is this a WPF bug?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting SnapsToDevicePixels="True" on the ListBox Item border? Since the thickness is 1 "Device independent unit" I am thinking that the border is falling on a pixel boundry.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the exact same problem, see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872401/properly-resize-wpf-listviews-last-column), and I never found a real answer. What I do nowadays is strip the scrollviewer from the listbox template and embed the entire listbox itself in a new scrollviewer. Doesn't work for all occasions, but it's a neat trick nonetheless.

The xaml looks like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>

  <ListBox>

    <!--strip default presenter-->
    <ItemsControl.Template>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <ItemsPresenter />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <!--data template goes here-->
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

  </ListBox>

</ScrollViewer>
```

I'm not a huge xaml wizard so if anybody could transfrom this into a reusable piece of code, by all means do so.